# Конструктор класса. Не пойму. C++

Tags: c++, конструктор

Доброго времени суток!

Изучаю книгу Дейтелов, 5 издание. И вот или переводчик перегнул или я не могу понять - куда суть.
На странице 162 даётся определение конструкторов. Привожу тяжёлый для поминания текст:

> 1. Для класса, который не определяет конструктора, конструктор по умолчанию  неявно создается компилятором. Такой конструктор не
>      инициали­зирует элементов  данных класса, однако вызывает конструктор
>      по умол­чанию для каждого элемента,  являющегося объектом другого
>      класса.

Не могу понять: конструктор, созданный неявно компилятором не инациализирует элеметы класса...
а каким боком он вызывает конструктор другого класса? Какого такого "другого" , если речь идёт
об одно конкретном? Не могу ухватить суть цепочки...

> 1. The compiler implicitly creates a default constructor in a class that does not define a constructor. Such a default constructor does
>      not initialize the class's data members, but does call the default
>      constructor for each data member that is an object of another class.

Вроде перевод достаточно правильный. То есть, компилятор видит, что в классе FistClass 
не указан явно конструктор и компилятор создаёт неявно конструктор. Это понятно.
А при чём тут вообще другие классы? Как этот конструктор может вызывать конструктор другого класса SecondClass (к примеру)? Зачем они о них сказано? Что этот абзац хочет мне сказать?

Comment: Есть класс A без конструтора, в нем поле int a. неявный компилятор создаст public: A(): a{} {}

Comment: Если в качестве поля класса выступает объект другого класса, то для него будет вызван конструктор по умолчанию, а если это будет, скажем, переменная типа int,  или double, или чего-то еще, у чего нет конструктопа по умолчанию, то проинциализировано оно не будет.

Comment: То есть, этот текст подразумевает, что мы имеем больше одного класса и FirstClass без конструктора, но использует  экземпляры данных из другого класса SecondClass и по этой цепочке, конструктор созданный компилятором, создаёт конструктор для элементов второго класса?

Я почему не могу понять - это определение идёт сразу после примера на рисунке 3.7 на котором имеем только один единственный класс и я не мог понять, как из него вызываются конструкторы для других классов. Которых вообще-то и нет в программе.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Скорее всего авторы книги пытались быть более-менее педантично корректными и хотели учесть тот факт, что конструкторы в С++ есть только у класс-типов. У не-класс типов конструкторов нет и быть не может по определению. То есть у типа `int`, например, никакого конструктора нет.

Именно так скорее всего и следует понимать данную фразу. То есть поля не класс-типов не инициализируются никак, а вот для полей, которые являются объектами классов (других, разумеется), вызываются конструкторы.

Вот для такого класса

```
struct S
{
  int i;
  std::string s;
};
```

компилятор неявно сгенерирует конструктор по умолчанию `S::S()`. Этот конструктор не будет никак инициализировать поле `i`, но будет вызывать конструктор по умолчанию для поля `s` (это, согласно книге, "data member that is an object of another class").

Фраза, разумеется, сформулирована кривовато.

---

Современный стандарт языка описывает поведение в таких случаях примерно так:

- Если пользователь не объявил явно никаких конструкторов для класса, компилятор неявно объявит и определит конструктор по умолчанию для этого класса <sup>†</sup>. Такой неявно определенный конструктор по умолчанию будет выполнять *инициализацию по умолчанию* всех подобъектов (полей и баз) класса.

  - Для подобъектов класс-типов *инициализация по умолчанию* означает вызов их конструкторов по умолчанию.
  - Для подобъектов типа "массив" *инициализация по умолчанию* означает инициализацию по умолчанию элементов массива.
  - Для подобъектов остальных типов *инициализация по умолчанию* означает отсутствие инициализации вообще.

  <sup>†</sup> - за исключением тех случаев, когда конструктор по умолчанию неявно определяться не будет: наличие в классе полей типа "ссылка", наличие подобъектов класс-типов без конструктора по умолчанию и с недоступным конструктором по умолчанию, наличие полей константных типов без инициализатора и без определенного пользователем конструктора по умолчанию и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо!

Я пока ничего не понял, но понял, что ответ есть и нужно учить дальше.
Вернусь к вашему ответу на шестой главе.

Comment: @Legioneroff, да чё тут понимать? Члены неинициализированного (в реализации, внутри конструктора класса) объекта будут содержать мусор, что логично. А для членов-объектов будет вызван конструктор (есть исключение при ромбовидном наследовании, но не суть), в смысле при включении, понимаешь? Конструктор создаёт объект, поэтому без него объекта не будет, а раз у тебя внутрь одного объекта завернут другой, то его тоже нужно создать.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον благодарю за ответ! Вот ты вроде русским языком всё рассказываешь... ;-) Ну ничего, я первый раз взялся за ООП и готов был к сложностям. Вернусь к твоему объяснению через пару глав книги.

Answer (score 0):

Мне ответили примером на Cyberforum. Когда запустил код, начал понимать в чём логика.
Надеюсь, что кому-то тоже поможет.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "Class A" << endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за поддержку.